# Can't print the json from ajax post using json_decode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using ajax to post data to a php script for work to be done...  Basically, I'm taking all the form variabes, and creating json...  Then taking this json and sending it to the controller script:

```
function createJSON() {
                 jsonObj = [];
                 $("input[class=form-control]").each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    item = {}
                    item [id] = value;
                    jsonObj.push(item);
                 });

             jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

             var request = $.ajax({
             url: "../../../../ajax/signupController.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: jsonData,
             dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function( msg ) {
            console.log(msg);
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });

            }
```

My code gets to the php script fine, and when I use "print_r" in php to print the output, I get this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [mail-firstname] => FName
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [mail-lastname] => Lname
    )
)
```

My problem is, I can't GET AT the elements...  I have tried:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));  
foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
print "<p>$key | $value</p>";
}
```

but I can't get at the array elements...  I get an error...  What am I missing about accessing the array after decoding the file contents?

Thanks.

Update:

Modified foreach:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    print $value->ccyear;//now I can get at individual elements
}
```

BUT ANY VALUE THAT HAS A DASH IS CAUSING THE SCRIPT TO FAIL...  For example, if the name is "mail-firstname" PHP thinks it's mail AND firstname...

Comment: `json_decode(,true)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your values are nested an extra level in your data. And they each have different keys, so it's hard to get at them. It would be better if you use the `id` as the keys of the top-level array, rather than nesting them:

```
jsonObj = {};
$("input[class=form-control]").each(function() {
    var id = this.id
    var value = this.value;
    jsonObj[id] = value;
 });
```

Then you should change your PHP to use the second argument to `json_decode()`, so you get an associative array instead of a `stdClass` object:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input', true));
```

I'm not really sure why you need to send JSON. Why not just use:

```
data: jsonObj;
```

Then you can access the inputs as `$_POST['mail-firstname']`, etc.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I didn't realize that you can create an array and then just send it as POST vals...  I thought you had to format the data as json to send it...  I will try your suggestion.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I couldn't get the post thing working, but I was able to use your suggestion of removing the nesting of the data...  Then I was able to access each value with: "print $data->{'mail-firstname'};"  Thanks so much!